Keycloak doesnt send cookies
we are using keycloak as container (connected to another mysql container on same server) on hetzner ubuntu server. We have two stages - develop and staging. They differ in so far that staging has a nginx load balancer and uses HTTPS while develop doesnt have a load balancer and uses only HTTP.
This is my Dockerfile for develop:
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.0 as builder

ENV KC_DB=mysql

ADD ./themes/tediro /opt/keycloak/themes/tediro

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.0
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=auth.d-tms.tediro.com
ENV KC_LOGLEVEL=ALL
ENV KC_DB=mysql
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/keycloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=xxx
ENV KC_ADMIN=admin
ENV KC_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxx
ENV KC_FEATURES=admin-fine-grained-authz
ENV KC_CACHE=local

ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=false

ENV JDBC_PARAMS="useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&connectTimeout=50000"
ENV JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS="-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=30000"
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=6000"

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev"]

This is for staging:
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.0 as builder

ENV KC_DB=mysql

ADD ./themes/tediro /opt/keycloak/themes/tediro

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.0
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=true
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=false
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=auth.s-tms.tediro.com
ENV KC_LOGLEVEL=ALL
ENV KC_DB=mysql
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/keycloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=xxx
ENV KC_ADMIN=admin
ENV KC_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxx
ENV KC_FEATURES=admin-fine-grained-authz
ENV KC_CACHE=local
ENV KC_PROXY=edge

ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true

ENV JDBC_PARAMS="useSSL=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&connectTimeout=50000"
ENV JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS="-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=30000"
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=6000"

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start"]


While staging is working fine, we are experiencing problems on develop.
In application code we use keycloak-js and call keycloak.login() to open keycloak hosted login page. This page sets 2 cookies: AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY and KC_RESTART . On clicking the login button these cookies are supposed to get send (thats at least happening on staging) but they are not getting sent on develop. This leads to a Cookie not found. Please make sure cookies are enabled in your browser.  error.
Problem is unrelated to browser settings since its happening everywhere and for everyone. Cookies Secure / SameSite options seem correct.
What could be a reason for keycloak to not send the cookies?
Tried to play around with all the options in the keycloak dockerfile.

For cookies to work you must use HTTPS, even locally. HTTP will block many of the cookies involved in OpenID-Connect due to the same site issue.
I blogged about how to detect and diagnose cookie problems in this blog post: https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/
